# Can github provide access control like gitolite?

Tags: github

some branches can be modified by a special team and can not be changed by other teams. We need the access control features like  gitolite provides. I want to know whether github can provide or not.

If we use Github Enterprise, we can write hooks to limit branches access. We can also use github features(such as 'code review') . Is it true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) is a simple (and complete) [authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html), so you can add it to any Git repository server that you want, including [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/).

That is exactly what the open-source version of "GitHub Enterprise" does: [GitLabHq](http://gitlabhq.com/) includes gitolite.
It supports [Gitolite V3 since GitLab 3.0](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/759) (released 4 days ago).

That being said, an open-source version will lack the code review feature, [which is included in GitHub Enterprise](https://github.com/blog/978-introducing-github-enterprise). I suppose the alternative is to link a GitLab with a [Gerrit server](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/).